# Was there ever a Seinfeld episode/pilot where he was of Irish ancestry?

Tags: seinfeld

I can't shake this memory of a scene of Jerry Seinfeld and George Costanza...I think they were moving a couch into/out of an apartment, and Jerry did an impression of his dad in an Irish accent.
I don't remember the content of what was said when Jerry was doing his impression.
I remember thinking to myself how young Jerry and George looked, lending weight to the notion that this would have been a very early episode.

The scene made me assume it must have been the Seinfeld pilot, or very early episode, when the larger cast, e.g. Jerry's dad, hadn't been worked out yet.
But I recently re-watched the [Seinfeld pilot](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098286/) and it had no such scene.
In fact, in the years since I'd formed the memory of this scene, I've found so little evidence of such a scene that I'm beginning to wonder if it was all just some fever dream.
I've searched online for various combinations and permutations of "Jerry and George moving couch", "Jerry Irish accent", "Jerry Irish dad", etc. with no luck finding any relevant answers.

**Does anyone in the community know of such a scene?** If anyone knows, please elaborate on the larger context: was this a scrapped pilot, or what episode was this, and what happened that changed this Irish ancestry of Jerry's character?

Answer (score 4):

The most likely scene is from *The Limo*.  This episode was in season 3, so, fairly early.

George and Jerry are pretending to be men named O'Brien and Murphy, in order to get a free limo ride home from the airport.  Unbeknownst to them, the real O'Brien is head of the Aryan Union, i.e. a white supremacist.  Later, they are confronted by a member of the Aryan Union, who suspects they may not be who they claim to be:

> Tim: You know it's funny. You don't look like an O'Brien.
>
> George: Me??
>
> George and Jerry laugh nervously.
>
> Tim: And you really don't look like a Murphy.
>
> Jerry: I may not look like a Murphy but I act like a Murphy.
>
> George: He's extremely Murphy. He's Murphy to a fault.
>
> Tim: Where are you from?
>
> Jerry: Dublin. Originally. Parents came over here when I was eighteen.
> Cereal famine. Couldn't get a bowl anywhere. Bad. 'Tis a beautiful country
> though; lush rolling hills, and the peat, ah the peat.
>
> Tim: Sounds more like Scottish.
>
> Jerry: We were right on the border.

There's another episode where Jerry does an Irish (or Scottish) accent, but there's no mention of parents.  *The Phone Message* (season 2, episode 4, which is very early; season 1 had only five episodes, so this is the ninth episode is the series):

> Jerry: (In awful Scots/Irish accent) Come on, try it. Let me hear you try
> a Scottish accent.
>
> Donna: That's Irish.
>
> Jerry: Irish, Scottish, what's the difference, lassie?

Comment: Just rewatched those two episodes based on your answer, and unfortunately, it was neither, but thank you.